# Can a VirtualBox Windows 7 virtual machine be installed on a USB hard disk?

Tags: macos, usb, external-disk, virtualization, virtualbox

My MacBook Air has only a 64G hard drive which is so small that I don't want to install virtual machines on it. I'm planning to buy a 1TB portable USB hard disk to run virtual machines. Has anyone tried running a Windows 7 VirtualBox virtual machine on a USB3.0 hard drive with success?

Comment: Did it work? If so which hard disk did you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

First you need to create the virtual machine, after you completed the wizard don't start the VM but go to the menu `Machine` -> `Show in Finder`

Copy the 3 files (`VM Name`.vbox, `VM Name`.vbox-prev, `VM Name`.vdi) to your external hard disk.

After select the VM inside virtualbox and go to menu `Machine` -> `Remove...` and click the button `Delete all files`

After go to menu `Machine` -> `Add..` and select the VM file you copied before.

Now the VM is inside virtualbox and runs from your external hard disk.